# Snowflake INSTR

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, instr

I am trying to extract the values in a string before the last ~ and first ~ using Snowflake

For example:

```
‘jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn~abc’

‘ftgftr~hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn~trf’

‘fgfgf~hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf~tddrf’

'jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc'
```

Expected output:

```
hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn

hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn

hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf

hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren
```

My query is trimming some of the values. Is there another option to achieve the above results?

```
select SUBSTR('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc',regexp_instr('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc', '[~]',1,1)+1,regexp_instr('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc', '[~]',1,2)) from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc', '~(.*?)~', 1, 1, 'e', 1) AS extracted_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer is the simplest form, but the REGEXP can be simpler as the `?` 0 or 1 is not binding to anything, and the grouping clause (the last `1`) can be dropped as it is the default:

```
select 
    $1 as txt
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '~(.*?)~', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as a1    
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTr(txt, '~(.*)~', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as a2
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTr(txt, '~(.*)~', 1, 1, 'e') as a3
from values
    ('123~~456'),
    ('123~~~456'),
    ('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn~abc'),
    ('ftgftr~hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn~trf'),
    ('fgfgf~hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf~tddrf'),
    ('jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc');
```

gives:

| TXT | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123~~456 |  |  |  |
| 123~~~456 | ~ | ~ | ~ |
| jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn~abc | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmn |
| ftgftr~hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn~trf | hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn | hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn | hhhhhiiiiii~jklmn |
| fgfgf~hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf~tddrf | hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf | hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf | hhhhhiiiiii~fgfgf |
| jjjjj~hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren~abc | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren | hhhhh-iiiiii~jklmererereren |